# how to add names to each object of a list

Tags: r

I have a list like below

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
str(my.list)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ y1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ y2: num [1:3] 4 5 6
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ y1: num [1:3] 3 2 1
  ..$ y2: num [1:3] 6 5 4
```

what i want to have is to add names as i wish to each object of this list 
for example

```
 $myFirst :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ y1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ y2: num [1:3] 4 5 6
 $mySecond :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ y1: num [1:3] 3 2 1
  ..$ y2: num [1:3] 6 5 4
```

I tired to do it by

```
myNam<-c("myFirst","mySecond")
names(myNam) <- sapply(my.list,paste)
```

where is the problem ?

A new data which the function does not work on it

```
df<- structure(list(A = structure(list(breaks = c(-10, -9, -8, -7, 
-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), counts = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
5L, 9L, 38L, 56L, 105L, 529L, 2858L, 17L, 2L, 0L, 2L), density = c(0.000276014352746343, 
0, 0.000276014352746343, 0.00138007176373171, 0.00248412917471709, 
0.010488545404361, 0.0154568037537952, 0.028981507038366, 0.146011592602815, 
0.788849020149048, 0.00469224399668783, 0.000552028705492686, 
0, 0.000552028705492686), mids = c(-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5, 
-4.5, -3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5), xname = "x", 
    equidist = TRUE), .Names = c("breaks", "counts", "density", 
"mids", "xname", "equidist"), class = "histogram"), B = structure(list(
    breaks = c(-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0), counts = c(2L, 
    0L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), density = c(0.125, 0, 0.375, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.0625, 0.1875), mids = c(-6.5, -5.5, -4.5, -3.5, 
    -2.5, -1.5, -0.5), xname = "x", equidist = TRUE), .Names = c("breaks", 
"counts", "density", "mids", "xname", "equidist"), class = "histogram"), 
    C = structure(list(breaks = c(-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
    0, 1), counts = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 22L, 110L, 3L), density = c(0.0123456790123457, 
    0.0123456790123457, 0.0246913580246914, 0.0308641975308642, 
    0.0864197530864197, 0.135802469135802, 0.679012345679012, 
    0.0185185185185185), mids = c(-6.5, -5.5, -4.5, -3.5, -2.5, 
    -1.5, -0.5, 0.5), xname = "x", equidist = TRUE), .Names = c("breaks", 
    "counts", "density", "mids", "xname", "equidist"), class = "histogram")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to assign the 'myNam' to the `names` of `my.list`

```
names(my.list) <- myNam
str(my.list)
#List of 2
#$ myFirst :'data.frame':       3 obs. of  2 variables:
# ..$ y1: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# ..$ y2: num [1:3] 4 5 6
#$ mySecond:'data.frame':       3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ y1: num [1:3] 3 2 1
#  ..$ y2: num [1:3] 6 5 4
```

or with `setNames`

```
setNames(my.list, myNam)
```

---

The OP's code

```
sapply(my.list,paste)
```

is looping through the `list` elements and `paste`ing the elements of the columns to a single string.

Comment: akrun , I accepted your answer and I liked it too, one question when I make a list and then I split it by df1<- my.list[[1]] and df2<- my.list[[2]] then when I put these two dos together again as list(df1,df2) it is not identical with my.list. it is because of the name which was removed during my split element. do you know how to avoid it ?

Comment: @nik It is because the `names` are not in the `list(df1, df2)`.  If you check with `all.equal` with `check.attributes=FALSE`, both are same i.e. `all.equal(list(df1, df2), my.list, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE`.

Comment: @nik An option would be to split it as a `list` by using `[` instead of `[[` so that the names will remain. i.e. `identical(c(my.list[1], my.list[2]), my.list)
#[1] TRUE`

Comment: if I want to take out the y1 from both object and put them in a data frame , do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @nik You can do `do.call(cbind, lapply(my.list, "[", "y1"))`

Comment: I pasted an example data above in my question and I tried your solution by do.call(cbind, lapply(mylist, "[[", "mids")) but not working

Comment: @nik Your 'df' is a nested `list`.  Try `lst <- lapply(df, function(x) x[["mids"]]); data.frame(lapply(lst, 'length<-', max(lengths(lst))))`

Comment: Great thanks, I tried to use your command to find the index of similar strings from df1 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4fb86bbf9a91d3c80410ba209e5f5a28 and df2 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ceeaa8597dea61d630b70215563cb21  using your command grep(paste(df2$dftNew.rn, collapse="|"), df1$V1) but it gave me error and did not find the indices

Comment: @nik Check the `str` of your dataset and see if it is different from the ones you showed here

Comment: I checked they have the same structure ! just this one is my real data and that one was a dummy

Comment: @nik If you have many elements, the `paste/collapse` approach may not work as there seems to be some ceiling for that and may need loop

Comment: I will undelete the question. would you please provide me with an answer based on my real data ? so that I will accept it

Comment: @nik which question you are undeleting (the one you asked in the morning)?  I will check on it.